# javascript - is an alert in a for-loop possible

Tags: javascript, for-loop, output, alert

Is writing an for-loop in an alert-statement possible?

Closer look to problem:
If I want to print the content of an array in one alert-statement. I am wondering if this is even possible.

an array :

```
myArray["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"]
```

Printing something like following with/in just one alert-statement:

```
Here your great content of myArray: 
a1 
a2 
a3 
a4
```

I am thinking about something like that:

```
alert("
Here your great content of myArray:\n" +

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
     myArray[i] + "\n";
}

);
```

Whereas of course it does not work .., but I kind of got stuck. Hope for constructive help, even if it might seem to be a silly question at first look.

Thanks in advance

Comment: IMHO no you can't :)

Comment: You could write something like `alert("Here your great content of myArray:\n" + myArray.join("\n"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I want to print the content of an array in one alert-statement.*

No need for a loop. Just use `.join()` to create a string separated by a newline character (or whatever character(s) you want).

```
alert("Here your great content of myArray:\n" + myArray.join("\n"));
```

---

And FYI, in ECMAScript 6, you'll be able to do this:

```
alert("Here your great content of myArray:\n" + [for (s of myArray) s + "\n"].join(""));
```

This can be handy for more complex situations.

Answer (score 2):

In `alert` you can pass a string. You passed also a `for` statement. This is not correct. In order you get that you want, I suggest you build a function that builds this string and then call it in the alert.

Something like this:

```
function getMessage(){
    var text="Here your great content of myArray:\n";    
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
     text += myArray[i] + "\n";
    }
}

alert(getMessage());
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is: can you convert a loop to a string? No you can't. This is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do:

```
var text;    
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
     text += myArray[i] + "\n";
}
alert("Here your great content of myArray:\n" + text);
```

Answer (score 0):

sort of:

```
alert("Here your great content of myArray:\n" + myArray.map(function(i){ 
          return i + "\n"
}).join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the for statement to the alert, but you can create an string with the array data and pass it to the alert as follow:

```js
array = ['some', 'text', 'to', 'print']

alert("message: " + array.map(function(s){return s;}))
```

join is good, but for dict objects you can't use it

```js
array = [{text:'some'}, {text:'text'}, {text:'to'}, {text:'print'}]

alert("message: " + array.map(function(s){return s['text'];}))
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be to use .join() as suggested by Jan but I am going to assume that you want to do something within the loop to decide which of the array elements to include e.g. only if it starts with a (which in this case would be all of them anyway but hey ho). In this case the way to do it would be to create the alert text as a variable and then alert the variable. Something like...

```
myArray["a1", "b2", "b3", "a4"]
msg = "Here is your great content of myArray:\n";
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if(myArray[i].substring(0,1) == "a") {
        msg+=myArray[i] + "\n";
        }
    }
alert(msg);
```

which will result in

```
Here is your great content of myArray:
a1
a4
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is a syntax error in you cannot execute javascript in side the alert function

```
var myArray=["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"];

var alertContent= "Here your great content of myArray:\n" ;

for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){ 
    alertContent+=myArray[i]+'\n';
}
alert(alertContent);
```

> you can use the above code to get the out put that you want